# How to encode a video using PHP?

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, video-encoding

I'm interested in installing [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) or somesuch on my server so I can upload files, automatically encode them to FLV and then serve up a embedded player to use on my pages.

The problem is that I don't know where to start. I don't want to have to spend days coding a web based encoding service, as I'm more interested in using an out of the box solution.

My research so far has led me to [`FFMPEG`](http://ffmpeg.org/) and possibly [`Gallery2`](http://gallery.menalto.com/): it has a `ffmpeg` integrated and the gallery 2 framework provides user accounts and FTP upload facilities.

Is anyone aware of other open source encoding solutions which you can install on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There is [ffmpeg extension for PHP](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`memcoder`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder), that does the same thing that `ffmpeg` does, but you *will have to* code the glue that binds `ffmpeg`/`memcoder`, `PHP` and the uploaded videos together.

The general workflow would be something like:

- Present form to user with PHP
- Upload file through `post`
- Verify uploaded file is video both client and serverside
- Store uploaded video in a known folder
- From PHP, run a `CLI` command with all the desired parameters and store the file in another known location
- Delete original file if success (optional)
- Store in DB the path to the created file
- Serve content
- Profit!

Comment: yeah I was hoping to avoid having to make custom codes if at all possible - I'd love to just configure an existing platform and minimise my workload.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [VLC](http://videolan.org) since it can transcode and act as a server for your FLV streams. The main application is a user interface to playback the video but it can be invoked from the command-line to do the serving - rather than playing.

Also there is libvlc which is the C library upon which VLC is written. VLC is based upon ffmpeg and might just make your life a little easier.

Comment: Hiya, I had a look at that but it makes no mention of FLV, which would be my preferred web format I think.

Comment: You're right, I can only see it listed as an input format. However it definitely works - I've been working on a project that converts raw H.264 video to FLV using VLC so I'm absolutely certain!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs for your chosen encoder, I have used ffmpeg successfully in the past. Then your workflow looks something like this.

- Handle the file upload with PHP
- Use exec() to shell out to your encoder and encode the video.
- When exec() returns, you can then serve the video in your page

ffmpeg was really easy to get up and running with a couple of command line arguments.

Comment: have to say the command line does look pretty simple! Again i'm really looking for a packaged solution if at all possible.

Comment: I really don't think you're going to find a packaged solution. and as the commandline should only take you about 10 minutes to figure out exactly what settings you're after, I wouldn't waste my time searching for a package that probably doesn't exist.

Comment: I fear you are correct, but I hope you're not! I don't really have time for this but it looks as if I'll have to properly put this on the jobs list. Thanks for the help!